# crystal reports function for calculating a value based on date range parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to calculate **Sum** of certain field value based on the date passed as parameter to the report.
I Need the following Calculations of value based on the date passed as parameter to the report:

1. Calculate the field value from 1st of the month to the date passed as Parameter.
2. Calculate the field value for the last month of the date passed as parameter.
3. Calculate the field value for the Previous day of the Date passed as parameter to the report.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula following this logic:

```
IF <Some Condition> Then Value ELSE 0
```

Then, simply SUM that formula.